# Changing the URL without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know if it's possible to change the contents of the URL in the browser without reloading the page?

I use jQuery and Ajax to load new parts of my page. When I choose "product one", the direct link would be `mysite.com/product1` and for "product two" would be `mysite.com/product2`, but I don't want to reload the site to these pages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to add hash `#` if you want to prevent page from reloading.

The css-tricks.com has an excellent screencast on that, have a look at:

[Best Practices with Dynamic Content](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/)

Answer (score 14):

its now possible with HTML_5..

chack this link... http://www.spoiledmilk.dk/blog/?p=1922

also facebook and google using this tric beside Hash(#) attribute

Comment: Great! For cross browser support you can use a library like history.js  https://github.com/balupton/history.js

Comment: Blog post is not found

Answer (score 7):

This is possible in HTML5. See a demo **[here](http://rebugged.com/code/html5/history.htm)**.

You can change the URL to another URL within the same domain, but can not change the domain for security reasons.

See the `history` interface in [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/history.html#history-0) for details.

Answer (score 7):

just use this one

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

Comment: Watch out for IE < 10: http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate. Use a polyfill like history.js.

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN** do that. Though likely you'll need a modern browser. Have a look at this page: http://www.20thingsilearned.com/ created by the Google Chrome team (I used Chrome 9 to read it). Changing pages doesn't reload the entire web page, but changes the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using the HTML5 History API. Check [this page](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)  and [this example](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/fer.html)

Answer (score -4):

You can't. Only if you change the hash, like sAc told you.

But.. May I ask WHY?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I find it useful when you change your content via ajax, and then your visitor wants to store the page he is looking at to bookmarks/send via email/ etc..

Comment: Like Yossarian said, that was one of my reasons. Also because the load of the page loading is less using ajax, and the loading of contens is better looking.

Comment: @Yossarian: I asked why he wants to use site.com/product, like the initial Q was (not hash).


@Paul: if you change more than 4-50% of your page content, you may want to rethink your strategy, because the speed you will gain with page transfer will be canceled by the DOM operation time :)

Comment: Wrong answer. In HTML5 it is posible to do that.

Comment: @Sasa, agree. But try to do that in IE9 :)